# Form handling using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following Code/Class 'ServiceRequest' and I wanna use this to write a POST form and Rest end-point in Spring Rest and Thymeleaf.

```
public class ServiceRequest {

 private Map<String, ServiceObject> serviceMap = new HashMap<>();
}

public class ServiceObject {
  private String id;
  private String name;
}
```

I done the java part but don't have any knowledge of handling Maps as a form object. I'll grateful if someone share any example or write some example Thymeleaf script here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like :

```
<tr th:each="serviceItem: ${ServiceRequest.serviceMap}">
    <td th:text="${serviceItem.key}">keyvalue</td>
    <td th:text="${serviceItem.value}">data</td>
</tr>
```

Use the th:each to iterate the map and what you will get is the item variables of type `java.util.Map.Entry`.
Reference [Doc](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach)